# How to send a callback method to another callback method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a custom jQuery Plugin, i have given the following options to indepandently modify the plugin accordingly :

```
onSuccess: false,                // callback
afterSuccess: false,             // callback
beforeRequest: 'searching ...',
```

This is how i handle these callback in my plugin,

```
/* --------------- Click Event on Dynamic Elements ------------------ */
this._afterSuccess( this.parent, this.$el, this.extraElement, this._removeContainer );
```

As you can see in the above code `this._removeContainer` is a method which i want to send the `afterSuccess` callback.

```
    _afterSuccess: function( parent, element, extraElement, removeContainer ) {

        var that = this;

        if( typeof this.options.afterSuccess == "function" ) {
            // Trigger callback if found
            this.options.afterSuccess.call( this, parent, element, extraElement, removeContainer );
        }
        else {
            parent.on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 

                var id = $(this).data('key');
                var text = $(this).text();

                that.$el.val(text);
                that._removeContainer();
                that.extraElement.val(id);
            });
        }
    }, 
    _removeContainer: function() {
        this.response_container.html('');
        this.extraElement.val('');
    },
```

This is how i am implementing the plugin:

```
$('#some_element').MyPlugin( {
    afterSuccess: function(parent, element, extraElement, removeContainer) {
            parent.on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 

                var id = $(this).data('key');
                var text = $(this).text();

                element.val(text);
                // Not working Generating Error
                removeContainer();

                extraElement.val(id);
            });
        }
} );
```

`removeContainer()` generating the error that **'response_container' of undefined** Is there any better way to call the `this._removeContainer()` in `afterSucess` callback method? OR i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set context to `removeContainer`, because now `this` in `removeContainer` refer to global `window`, but in `window` there is not `response_container`, like this

```
this.options.afterSuccess.call( this, parent, element, extraElement, $.proxy( removeContainer, this ) );
```

**Update**

```
this.options.afterSuccess.call( this, parent, element, extraElement, removeContainer.bind(this) );
```